# Jquery not loading / being recognised in my file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jquery, which I have successfully used before in the same way, but for some reason it just is not being recognised in this file. At the moment I am simply trying to get jquery to work and am using an  alert to see if anything would happen when I clicked my button, but nothing.

My code:

I have tried moving the jquery script to different areas (inside head, inside body etc) based on other articles. I've also tried the `$( document ).ready(function() {` instead of the short version I have above, which also doesn't work.

The file name and location is definitely correct.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thanks :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My program</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <script src="./src/myProgram.js">
    </script>
    <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <section>
      <h2>My Program</h2>
      <h3 id="message"></h3>
      <button id="button1" class "button">Button</button>
    </section>
  </center>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Converted what you had into a runnable snippet here in the page and moved the script tags inside the `<body>` and it works fine

Comment: So, what's the question again? Works fine.

Comment: What's in `<script src="./src/myProgram.js">`? If you remove that, do you still get the same issue?

Comment: Any error in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: The snippet works :/